# Kali Linux chmod 666

Tags: linux, chmod, ls

I'm using a user I created with adduser that I logged into. I created a directory through this user (not root) and changed permissions from the standard 644 to 666 (no pun intended) with chmod 666 "filename."

Now I cannot acces it. When I use "ls "filename,"" I just get permission denied. I didn't get this, have I misunderstood something entirely?

I wanted to give more access to other users, not remove my own access. What Should I have done?

Comment: For directories the standard is `755`. See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/21252/108618).

Answer (score 1):

Directory created should have the execute permission in order for the user to change directory into it.(move into the directory).

Unix wont allow you to enter into a directory that doesnt have a execute permission

Also check what is the `umask` value set for the user, usually its either 002 or 022 but i never saw it as 122